# Universal hashing techniques based on matrix multiplication

Tags: hash, universal-hash

The article [here](http://www.i-programmer.info/programming/theory/2664-universal-hashing.html) says below, about a universal hashing technique based on matrix multiplications.

*"However, there is a little known method based on using a random matrix. It has lots of advantages - it's a universal family"*

I tried to hard to find the source paper of the same to dig deeper but could not. Any references about the technique ?

Comment: Proving \epsilon-universality of random matrix hashing sounds an execise. I once found proofs in Shoup's textbook.

Comment: The method is described in CMU's Lecture 10 notes on hashing: https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~avrim/451f11/lectures/lect1004.pdf

Answer (score 3):

The source of this result, although it can be found in many other places, is the  Wegman-Carter paper ['Universal classes of hash functions'](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0022000079900448). More specifically, Proposition 9 in page 151.